# C89: Multithreaded Random Values with rand_r()

Tags: c, multithreading, random, pthreads, c89

So, I was curious how someone could get random values across multiple threads with the rand_r command. If I used time(NULL) for the seed everyone ends up with the sam seed because the threads are created so close together. There actions are all based on that random seed, so all the threads remain identical for the remainder of my program. How would one get [ USING RAND_R(*int seed) ] a random number that differed across all threads?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call `time(NULL)` to get the first seed and the second seed. Then you can use the second seed to generate the third seed. And so on.

Comment: What about just using the seed = time(NULL) + thread_id? Or XOR them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `arc4random` to generate the seed values for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man3/rand.3.html) for rand_r on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 suggests:

> The  value  pointed to by the `seedp` argument of `rand_r()` provides only a very small amount 
>   of state, so this function will be a weak pseudo-random generator.  Try [`drand48_r(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man3/drand48_r.3.html) instead.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Not to mention that's only true for Ubuntu, the man page may state something differently on another platform.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My assignment asks me to find a random number for my sleep times, but it insists I use rand_r... I saw this, but was trying to find an answer within the guidelines

Comment: The only suggestion I have to use a global variable for the seed variable, and only populate it at the start of the program, i.e. not prior to each `rand_r()` call.